# How to verify successful execution of queries using sqlcmd?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcmd

I am using the **sqlcmd** utility to run a sequence of sql queries in a script file. One of the simple queries is given below. The command I use to run the sqlcmd utility is:

```
sqlcmd.exe -m-1 -r 1 -S . -E -d test -i "D:\Recycle\Sp_tempTable1.sql".
```

I am running the **sqlcmd** utility from C# code. This works fine--the query is executed and the table is successfully created.

What I want is the utility to return something which tells me all of the queries in the input file ran successfully. Is there any means to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Using the -o flag allows you to specify an output file. This file will contain the number of affected rows and/or any errors encountered by the command. However, it would be MUCH easier to run the query from managed code using the [System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) namespace so you can implement standard try -> Exception -> catch error handling.